# How to change the from address in send grid email

Tags: spring-boot, email, jakarta-mail, sendgrid-api-v3

I have configured the send grid API for email service in my spring boot APP. And, it's working fine. I wanted to change the from address as "no-reply@xyz.com" instead of "apikey". But, I couldn't.

Also, I tried it using JavaMaiSender. But, no luck.

Could you please anyone let me know?

```
    public void sendEmailUsingSendgrid(EmailRequest emailRequest) throws IOException {
        String text = getEmailTemplate(emailRequest);
        SendGrid sg = new SendGrid(sendGridApi);
        sg.addRequestHeader("X-Mock", "true");
        Request request = new Request();
        Mail mail = new Mail();
        mail.setFrom(new Email(emailRequest.getFr()));
        mail.setSubject(emailRequest.getSbjt());
        mail.addContent(new Content("text/html", text));
        List<String> mailList = Arrays.asList(emailRequest.getTo());
        for (String to : mailList) {
            Personalization p1 = new Personalization();
            p1.addTo(new Email(to));
            mail.addPersonalization(p1);
        }
        mail.setReplyTo(new Email("noreply@xyz.com"));
        request.setMethod(Method.POST);
        request.setEndpoint("mail/send");
        request.setBody(mail.build());
        sg.api(request);
    }
```

Properties

```
# SENDGRID
sendgrid-api-key=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
```

Comment: Add your configuration in properties and  code

Comment: Per the JakartaMail docs, [mail.smtp.from](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/mail/docs/api/com/sun/mail/smtp/package-summary.html) sets the values of the return address and [MimeMessage::setReplyTo](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/mail/docs/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.html#setReplyTo-javax.mail.Address:A-) can be used to control the reply to addresses.

Comment: @Rono I have added my properties and code, I'm trying to change the from email address instead showing as "apikey" which is not valid.